# Customize Visio Timeline Template Date Format Options

Tags: microsoft-visio, templates

I'm working in Visio 2013 with the Timeline Template which is one of the built-in options available when I pick File | New:

[image: Like so...]

This template contains a Stencil with timeline shapes that have dates or date ranges attached to them.  When you drop a shape from the stencil you get a pop-up dialog that lets you configure the shape:

[image: Dialog]

Note the drop down list of **Date Formats**.  There is a very long list of options here, but it doesn't include the one that I really need, which is `MMM d`, in other words, I'd like to see 2015-08-16 come out like this: **Aug 16**.

The context of the diagram is such that year is completely understood so it just wastes space.  Also, I'm working cross-culturally so an option like `MM-d` could potentially be confusing.

I've found that by editing the Shape Sheet for these shapes, I can force the type of display that I want using this:

```
User.visMask ="{{MMM d}}"
```

or similar changes, depending on the type of shape involved.

The problem with this approach is that I have to change every single shape and if I ever reconfigure the shape, or copy/paste it, or anything else that causes a change to the date, then the format reverts to one of the options in the pop-up dialog box.

**Is there any way to modify the options in the *Date Format* drop down list dialog box for the Timeline Template?**

Comment: Hi Joel! I have this _exact_ question. Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @bitsmack What I eventually discovered is that these formatting options are all compiled into the stencil's binary and there's just no way to hack this, unfortunately.  I was hoping I'd find an xml file or something somewhere, but it's just baked right in.  Sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Now I know not to waste time trying :) Take care!